# sed using array search and replace last column on csv file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

I'm looking a solution with sed command to search and replace strings on last column of csv file and here the search patterns I'm calling from an array. Below script looks for 3rd and 4th column which causes a mismatch in the output.

Here i need your help how i can tell sed to look only on the last column.

file1.txt

```
QCQP
TXTT
QCQT
YYTH
```

file2.txt

```
TTYY
JPEK
QCQC
TTYE
```

Original
output.csv

```
[Input]
String1

[Data]
ID,Name,Class,Context,Code
1,jack,6,QCQT,QCQP
2,john,5,QCQP,TXTT
3,jake,3,TTXX,QCQT
4,jone,3,TXTT,YYTH
```

Below is my script which I used for this setup, but here this sed command search for all occurrence instead of looking for the last column separated by comma.

```
#!/bin/bash
filein=file1.txt
fileout=file2.txt
pre=$(cat $filein)
post=$(cat $fileout)
prear=($pre)
postar=($post)
typeset -p prear postar

for (( i=0; i<${#prear[@]}; ++i )); do
sed -i -e 's/'"${prear[$i]}"'/'"${postar[$i]}"'/g' output.csv
done
```

Expected result

output.csv

```
[Input]
String1

[Data]
ID,Name,Class,Context,Code
1,jack,6,QCQT,TTYY
2,john,5,QCQP,JPEK
3,jake,3,TTXX,QCQC
4,jone,3,TXTT,TTYE
```

Using awk command I'm able to figure out similiar occurance, but the below works with a single variable, also not with comma seperator but with array this fails.

```
awk -F "," '{gsub(c,d,$(NF)); print}' c=$a d=$b file.txt
```

In addition, if using awk or gawk for this purpose, i would need to specify the variable name as input. Because the input files "file1.txt, file2.txt" and output files with .csv filenames will not be same all the time. Actually I'm accepting them as first, second and third argument in the script and then reading the contents from that variable.

For eg:- Here users can choose any name file as input. Here I'm not sure how to call the array in awk/gawk

```
#!/bin/bash
input1=$1
input2=$2
Output=$3

inp1=$(cat $input1)
inp2=$(cat $input2)
out=$(cat $Output)
inp1ar=($inp1)
inp2ar=($inp2)
outar=($out)

I would like to expect to call the array variable to read the contents 

gawk -i inplace '
.. some condition ..
' {inp1ar} {inp2ar} {outar}
```

Please advise

Thanks
Jay

Comment: `pre=$(file1.txt)` and `post=$(file2.txt)` say to invoke a subshell and *execute* the files named `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` which in turn should be generating error messages, which in turn should be leaving the two variables empty, which in turn should be causing some error messages when running the loop; *assuming* you want to load the contents of the files into arrays consider: `pre=( $(<file1.txt) )` and `post=( $(<file2.txt) )`; and to verify contents: `typeset -p pre post`

Comment: after the code modification did you run `typeset -p pre post`? if you did you would find that your edit loads the values into the variables as strings ... *not* as arrays; consider updating the code with the recommended change from my 1st comment

Comment: @markp-fuso but i ran my script without this ```typeset -p pre post``` which works fine. This is new information to me, sure i will update in my code and page as well

Comment: there's no way your code (as presented here) performed correctly; enable debug mode (`set -xv`) and run again, then review the debug output ... the code you've posted here is not populating `pre` and `post` as arrays which in turn should be causing `sed` to generate errors

Comment: *`works fine`* ... did you verify the contents of `output.csv` both before *and* after you ran your code?

Comment: @markp-fuso , i tested and now it the array is reflecting fine. And I checked the contents of output.csv

Comment: if the entries in `file1.txt` or `file2.txt` contain white space then one safer approach to loading the arrays would be: `mapfile -t pre < file1.txt` and `mapfile -t post < file2.txt`

Comment: The correct way to create an array of *lines of a file* is to use the bash builtin [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) command: `mapfile -t inp1ar < "$input1"`

Comment: in your latest update this: `{inp1ar} {inp2ar} {outar}` should be replaced with: `${inp1ar} ${inp2ar} ${outar}` but, you can't pass arrays to `awk` like this; you would need to convert the arrays into a structure that looks like a file to `awk`, eg, `<(printf "%s\n" "${inp1ar}")`, but since you initially pulled the array from a file you could simplify the script by having `awk` read the file directly, ie, replace this: `{inp1ar} {inp2ar} {outar}` with this: `"$1" "$2" "$3"`; having said that ...

Comment: `-i inplace` is going to overwrite *all* three of the input files (see my answer for one way to use `-i inplace` while also turning the feature on/off for individual files (via the `inplace::enable={0,1}` clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for this. With GNU awk:

```bash
gawk '
  BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
  ARGIND == 1 {f1[FNR] = $1; next}
  ARGIND == 2 {map[f1[FNR]] = $1; next}
  {$NF = map[$NF]; print}
' file1.txt file2.txt original.csv
```

```
ID,Name,Class,Context,
1,jack,6,QCQT,TTYY
2,john,5,QCQP,JPEK
3,jake,3,TTXX,QCQC
4,jone,3,TXTT,TTYE
```

But with sed, you can dynamically build up a sed program using file1 and file, and than apply that to the original csv

```bash
sed "$(paste -d " " file1.txt file2.txt | sed 's/^/s:,/; s/ /$:,/; s/$/:/')" original.csv
```

Execute that piece-by-piece to see how it all fits together.

---

To accomodate the updated csv file with "prefix" lines: (untested)

```bash
gawk '
  BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
  ARGIND == 1 {f1[FNR] = $1; next}
  ARGIND == 2 {map[f1[FNR]] = $1; next}

  BEGINFILE {start = 0; header = 1}
  start {if (header) {header = 0} else {$NF = map[$NF]}}
  {print}
  $1 == "[Data]" {start = 1}
' file1.txt file2.txt original.csv
```

---

Given the skeleton of a script you have in your recent edit:

First, it is **crucial** to quote your variable names: `cat "$input1"` -- failure to do that will result in the "I'm falling as argument or some other variable name" that you report.

Next, there's no need to read the contents of the files in the bash part of the script: awk will do that.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
input1="$1"
input2="$2"
Output="$3"

gawk -i inplace '.. some condition ..' "$input1" "$input2" "$Output"
```

See how the variables are all (double) quoted everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the issues related to the population of the `pre[]` and `post[]` arrays it appears OP's `bash` code should now function correctly so, looking at an `awk` solution ...

Assumptions:

- `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` have the same number of rows (ie, each row in `file1.txt` has a matching row in `file2.txt`)
- none of the files contain commas as part of the data (ie, commas only show up as delimiters in `output.csv`)
- if the 5th column from `output.csv` does not have a match in `file1.txt` then we leave the row alone
- the `[Data]` section is the last section in `output.csv` (otherwise OP may need to add logic to turn off the replacement logic once the `[Data]` section has been processed)

Adding a line to `output.csv` that does not have a match in `file1.txt`:

```
$ cat [Input]
String1

[Data]
ID,Name,Class,Context,Code
1,jack,6,QCQT,QCQP
2,john,5,QCQP,TXTT
3,jake,3,TTXX,QCQT
4,jone,3,TXTT,YYTH
5,mary,7,XXXX,9999                 # this line should not be modified
```

We'll make use of `paste` to combine `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` into a single data set:

```
$ paste -d',' file1.txt file2.txt
QCQP,TTYY
TXTT,JPEK
QCQT,QCQC
YYTH,TTYE
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN                  { FS=OFS=","; replace=0 }     # initially we are not in "replace" mode
FNR==NR                { map[$1]=$2; next }          # 1st file: build map[] array entries
replace && ($5 in map) { $5=map[$5] }                # 2nd file: if in "replace" mode and 5th field is an index in the map[] array then replace the 5th field 
$1 == "[Data]"         { replace=1 }                 # enable "replace" mode
1                                                    # print current line
' <(paste -d',' file1.txt file2.txt) output.csv
```

This generates:

```
[Input]
String1

[Data]
ID,Name,Class,Context,Code
1,jack,6,QCQT,TTYY
2,john,5,QCQP,JPEK
3,jake,3,TTXX,QCQC
4,jone,3,TXTT,TTYE
5,mary,7,XXXX,9999                 # line was not modified
```

While OP's `sed` code updates the original file (due to the use of the `-i` flag), this `awk` solution does *not* update the original file.  If OP needs to update the original file then there are a couple options:

- save this output to a temp file and then `mv tempfile output.csv`
- if using `GNU awk` we can make use of the `inplace` module

Assuming `GNU awk` is available we can make the following changes to our `awk` code to enable updating of the `output.csv`:

```
awk -i inplace '
BEGIN                  { FS=OFS=","; replace=0 }
FNR==NR                { map[$1]=$2; next }
replace && ($5 in map) { $5=map[$5] }
$1 == "[Data]"         { replace=1 }
1
' inplace::enable=0 <(paste -d',' file1.txt file2.txt) inplace::enable=1 output.csv
```

Where:

- `-i inplace` - loads the `inplace` module
- `inplace::enable=0` - disables `inplace` processing for the 'file' containing the `paste` results
- `inplace::enable=1` - enables `inplace` processing for the `output.csv` file

This generates:

```
$ cat output.csv
[Input]
String1

[Data]
ID,Name,Class,Context,Code
1,jack,6,QCQT,TTYY
2,john,5,QCQP,JPEK
3,jake,3,TTXX,QCQC
4,jone,3,TXTT,TTYE
5,mary,7,XXXX,9999
```

Comment: i tested the inplace edit, but I'm getting this error ```warning: inplace_begin: Cannot stat `inplace::enable=0' (No such file or directory)```

Comment: @user183980 the error message indicates `awk` thinks `inplace::enable=0` is a filename and so it generates an error when it can't find a file with said name; this is either an issue with the order in which the clause is used (eg, you're using it incorrectly in your invocation) or perhaps your `awk` version does not support this feature; what does `awk --version` return? did you run the script *exactly* as shown in the answer or did you modify it?

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso my awk version ```GNU Awk 4.2.1``` . Yes I copied the same only changed the input and output files

Comment: not sure what you mean by *`changed the input and output files`* ... this is the part that, if not 'changed' properly can lead to the error you're reporting; would need to see the *exact* changes you made

Answer (score -1):

This `sed` should work:

```
$ cat f
ID,Name,Class,Context,Code
1,jack,6,QCQT,QCQP
2,john,5,QCQP,TXTT
3,jake,3,TTXX,QCQT
4,jone,3,TXTT,YYTH

$ sed -r 's/,(QCQP|TXTT|QCQT|YYTH)$/,aaa/' f f
ID,Name,Class,Context,Code
1,jack,6,QCQT,aaa
2,john,5,QCQP,aaa
3,jake,3,TTXX,aaa
4,jone,3,TXTT,aaa
ID,Name,Class,Context,Code
1,jack,6,QCQT,aaa
2,john,5,QCQP,aaa
3,jake,3,TTXX,aaa
4,jone,3,TXTT,aaa
```

But IMHO `awk` is better for this task.

Comment: here my expected output not matching. Also the search pattern will be dynamic.